Why can't my class be run after declaring package and be found by another class in the same package/folder?
I am having problems understanding how packages work. Not using any IDE.
I have the following folder structure:
~/dropbox/api/data
Inside the data folder, there are (only) Producer.java, Consumer.java.
api
├── data
     ├── Consumer.java
     ├── Producer.java
     └── Producer.class

package data;

public class Producer {
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //do some production
   }

   public static Producer getProducer() {
      //call constructor and return instance
   }
}
----------------
package data;

public class Consumer {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Producer worker = getProducer();
   }

}

I cd to data folder and javac Producer.java to compile Producer.class in the same folder. Then when I run java Producer, I get Error: Could not find or load main class Producer
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Producer (wrong name: data/Producer).
Same error, when I tried java Producer and java data.Producer from the parent api folder, and java data.Producer in data folder.


What's wrong here? If I remove the package data;, it compiles (javac) and runs (java) fine in data folder.

Also, when I tried javac Consumer.java, I get error: cannot find symbol Producer. They are in the same folder and declared same package.

What's wrong here?


The java command requires that you specify the fully qualified name of the class. So, java Producer will never work; you must type java data.Producer.
But that's not all.
Package follows dir. So, when you type java data.Producer as you must, java tries to load data/Producer.class from each entry on the classpath. By default, the current dir is on the classpath, but if you've been messing with e.g. the CLASSPATH environment variable it might not be. To make sure that's not the problem, java -cp . data.Producer.

Same error, when I tried java Producer and java data.Producer from the parent api folder,

No, you messed up there somehow. java data.Producer from the api folder will work. Just to be sure, try java -cp . data.Producer (and if that does work, unmessup whatever you messed up with the CLASSPATH variable. Or just get used to doing that, it's not a bad idea).

Also, when I tried javac Consumer.java, I get error: cannot find symbol Producer.

Same problem, you need to run javac data/Consumer.java from the api dir.
There's a reason you don't use javac directly and instead use a build tool or IDE.

I added a screenshot. The folder structure is ibapi/historicalData in which there are HistoricalDataDownloader.class, com folder. Inside HistoricalDataDownloader.java, I have import com.ib.client.* It seems error is from that import. When I remove package historicalData, it works fine. That com/ib/client/* contains 3rd-party source needed for the HistoricalDataDownloader class to run.

Shall I move the com folder out of historicalData into the parent ibapi folder, so historicalData and com are siblings? All source files inside com/ib/client are declared package com.ib.client, so import com.ib.client inside HistoricalDataDownloader.java should work?

@limestreetlab I suggest you use an IDE (IntelliJ, Eclipse, NetBeans, VS Code, etc.) and possibly a build tool (Maven, Gradle, etc.). It will make developing non-trivial Java applications easier. That said, if your code depends on a third-party library, then you need to point at it when compiling (and running) your application. See the -cp / -classpath / --class-path or -p / --module-path options. Though you say "source", so perhaps you actually want -sourcepath / --source-path? Note dependencies in Java are virtually always precompiled, so that would be atypical.

Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.
Currently the screenshot bears only a passing resemblance to the locations of what you need to compile anyway. You'd be much better off to do cd ~/dropbox/ibapi;find . -name \*.class -exec rm '{}' \;tree . and post the output as formatted code

@limestreetlab dropbox/ibapi is the 'root' for your code, but, dropbox/ibapi/historicaldata is the root of the com.ibm stuff. That's not going to work. historicaldata is a top level package. com is a top level package. Both directories niet to be siblings of each other. In the errors in your screenshot, the thing to focus on is the com.ibm not found part. Not the 'cannot load class' part - it cannot load your class BECAUSE com.ibm is not found. If you're struggling with this: Walk before you run. Make a dead simple package-based java source file that has zero deps and work with that.
